# RasPi VNC Issues - Connection refused by the computer

Tags: vnc, pi-3a+

I am getting a bit desperate here since I do not understand how to fix this issue.
My problem: using a RasPi3 A+

```
`vnc server is running: status response via ssh
*systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service
vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-05-03 08:57:55 CEST; 28s ago
 Main PID: 877 (vncserver-x11-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
           |-877 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
           `-878 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service
systemd[1]: Started VNC Server in Service Mode daemon.`
```

But then I am trying to connect using VNC viewer and "connection refused by computer" error is thrown.
Sure, I could use the ssh X11 forwarding workaround but I would like to understand why I cannot connect. It appears that the ServerManager is somehow not started an it would start after some time and then the connection works. But how do I do it in a controlled fashion?

Thanks a lot for your inputs,
Thomas

Comment: What OS? How did you setup VNC?